# For loop for phylogenetic trees

Tags: for-loop, multiprocessing, slurm

I am using a phylogenetic software called RAxML and I wnat to build single trees for each phylip file. For a directory with three phylip files, I did the following

```
 ##files in directory
 Ortho1.phy Ortho6.Phy Ortho6.Phy

for f in /home/Single_trees/trimmed_alignment/*.phy; do raxmlHPC -f a -x 100 -m PROTGAMMAAUTO -p 100 -s $f -N 100 -n $f.tree; done;
```

But this always gives me an error saying $ symbol is not allowed.

```
raxmlHPC: axml.c:5236: analyzeRunId: Assertion `0' failed.
```

Error character / not allowed in run ID

Is there a better way to do it? I tried using job arrays for non-sequential named files using this link here https://rc.fas.harvard.edu/resources/documentation/submitting-large-numbers-of-jobs-to-odyssey/ but was unable to implement it.

This is what I tried for array job submission:

```
 #!/bin/bash -l
 #
 # raxml.sbatch
 #
 #SBATCH -J consensus       # A single job name for the array
 #SBATCH -p high # best partition for single core small jobs
 #SBATCH -n 12              # one core
 #SBATCH -N 1              # on one node
 #SBATCH -t 100:00:00         # Running time of 2 hours
 #SBATCH --mem 18000        # Memory request of 4 GB
 #SBATCH -o raxml_%A_%a.out # Standard output
 #SBATCH -e raxml_%A_%a.err # Standard error
 module load raxml

  for FILES in /home/aligned_fasta/.phy; do
   echo ${FILES}
  done;

  # grab out filename from the array exported from our 'parent' shell
  FILENAME=${FILES[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]}

  # make & move into new directory, and run!
 mkdir ${FILENAME}_out
 cd ${FILENAME}_out
 raxmlHPC -f a -x 100 -m PROTGAMMAAUTO -p 100  -s $FILENAME -N 100 -n $FILENAME.tree 

 #Now, we grab all the appropriate files and submit them en-batch with an  array:
 # grab the files, and export it so the 'child' sbatch jobs can access it
```

export FILES=($(ls -1 .phy))

```
 # get size of array
 NUMPHY=${#FILES[@]}
 # now subtract 1 as we have to use zero-based indexing (first cell is 0)
 ZBNUMPHY=$(($NUMPHY - 1))

 # now submit to SLURM
 if [ $ZBNUMPHY -ge 0 ]; then
 sbatch --array=0-$ZBNUMPHY raxml.sbatch 
 fi
```

I submitted using sbatch --array=0-10 raxml.sh but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out something. Basically, I will rename the files so that they are consecutive and I can just use slurm.

```
 ls *.phy | cat -n | while read num file; do mv $file ${file/./.$num.}; done
```

So the files will be

```
 Ortho1.1.phy Ortho6.2.Phy Ortho6.3.Phy
```

Then you can do it the following way:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
# SBATCH -J tree

###### Standard out and Standard Error output files with the job number in the name.
#SBATCH -o tre_%A.%a.out
#SBATCH -e tre_%A.%a.err

###### number of nodes
###SBATCH --nodes=6
###SBATCH --nodes=6

###### number of processors
#SBATCH -n 16
###SBATCH --cpus-per-task=4

###### Spread the tasks evenly among the nodes
####BATCH --ntasks-per-node=8

###### coupled with array
####SBATCH --ntasks=1-179

#SBATCH --time=300:00:00

#SBATCH -p high

#SBATCH --mem 24000 

###### Want the node exclusively
### SBATCH --exclusive

#SBATCH --array=1-3

module load raxml

for i in $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID.phy
do
echo $i
done

### tree
 raxmlHPC-PTHREADS -f a -x 100 -m PROTGAMMAAUTO -p 100 -T 16 -s $i -N 100 -n $i.tree
```

This will give you separate trees that you can use to build a consensus tree.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be bootstrapping and obtaining the consensus phylogeny, in which case there is a special case within RAxML to do this. When I have minute I will post it here.